# html5 canvas wrong dimensions of rotated text

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to visualize text on a canvas vertically (45° counter-clockwise rotated). I know that this is possible with the html5 canvas, so this is what I wrote:

```
function drawText(canvas, text){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.translate(70, 140);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI*1.5);

    ctx.fillStyle     = "blue";
    ctx.textBaseline  = "top";

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.font = '700 55pt Verdana'
    ctx.fillText(text, 10, 20);
}
```

and the canvas that this is used on has this styles (+ inherrited styles)

```
canvas.trigger {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        width:65;
        height:98;
    }

a.trigger3{
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
left: 0;
width:60px;
height:98px;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing:0px;
font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
color:#fff;
font-weight: 700;
background:#333333;
border:2px solid #444444;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
display: block;
z-index:1;
}
```

The code has this result:

[image]

while the final result should be a button (that one with the rounded courners) and the whole text "Details".
There are two problems with this code: first of all, when I give a normal size for the ctx.font (e.g. 12pt) the text is too small to read and the second one: when I use a bigger font-size like in this code (55pt) the height of the text is perfect, but it is too long (heigh when you rotated it) so only a part of the text ("Details") is shown.

Does someone see a problem with this code? I think it would be style-related, because when I do the same with no other styles in the Tryit Editor of w3schools the font is perfect.

Comment: By the way, for playing around I'd recommend using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and that you *never* use W3Schools as a reference. You can see a long list of reasons why at [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: thank you for the tip, i tried the code in JSFiddle and it worked there too:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfzCS/
like you see in the example the proportions of the text aren't messed up, but in my resulting program (see image above) the text is stretched out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is being caused by the fact that you're setting the width and height of the canvas through a style sheet, instead of the width/height properties of the canvas element. For some reason setting the canvas width/height through its style sheet causes weird scaling issues.

If you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/bfzCS/2/, you'll see what I mean. The same code you provided, I just changed it so that it would set the width/height by way of style sheet. Notice how it's all stretched out? I think it has something to do with the fact that the stylesheet width/height actually controls the rendering surface, where as the width/height element properties control the size of the element.

Comment: Yep. Your HTML will need to include something like <canvas width="65" height="98" />. Or you could problematically set the width and height properties of the element (not the CSS properties of the same name, but the actual element properties) at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you specific goal is vertically aligned text, there is a CSS property that could be of help:

```
p.trigger {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
```